# Set of positive functions in $L^2$ is closed

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded set and define the set of almost everywhere positive functions on $L^2(\Omega)$ as $$A:=\{ f \in L^2(\Omega): f(x) \geq 0 \text{ for almost all }x \in \Omega \}.$$ How can I show that $A$ is a closed set, in the sense that if $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\;\subset{A}$ such that $||f_n-f||_{L^2(\Omega)}\rightarrow0$ we have $f\in A$? Thank you for any hints.

Comment: There is a useful lemma connecting convergence in $L^2$ and pointwise convergence almost everywhere of a subsequence.

Comment: You mean "non-negative" not "positive". This is an important distinction: $0$  is not positive.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $f$ isn't positive a.e., then there is some set $S$ of positive measure s.t. $f(S) < \frac{1}{k}$ (if all such sets have measure $0$, then set of points where $f$ is negative, as union of countably many sets with measure $0$, itself has measure $0$).

But then we have $\|f_n - f\| \geq \int_S |f(x) - f_n(x)|\, dx \geq \int_S \frac{1}{k}\, dx = \frac{1}{k}\cdot \mu(S)$, so $f_n \not\to f$.